# Is It possible to use Custom sounds and skins using command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is it possible to use custom sounds or skins in vanilla minecraft using command blocks? Or do I have to use mods for this?

I want to create a map in which when one enters a certain room a sound plays, or the NPCs (as Villagers) having custom skins. Can I use command blocks for this?

Comment: you can use *resourcepacks* to alter the appearance of villagers and add custom sounds which then can be played from a commandblock using the `/playsound` command.

Comment: Why the downvote? Anything I should improve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you cannot make custom or new textures/sounds using command blocks, you can play vinilla Minecraft sounds and have players download a resourcepack before playing your map so they see the textures you want them to.

Comment: Oh yes, I had forgotten about resourcepacks. Thanks!